# there is an error of student name is not defined

Tags: python, function

discount

```py
bill = input("student or regular: ")  #this code is to apply discount  
print(bill)

student = student()  #student 10% discount

regular = regular()

if bill == student:

     def student(x):
         return x - (x * (10 / 100))

         x = float(input("Enter the price: "))

         print(student(x))

if bill == regular:  #regular 5% discount

     def regular(y):
         return y - (y * (5 / 100))
         y = float(input("Enter the price: "))
         print(buyer(y))

else:
     print("errroor")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). This is *not a discussion forum* and we *do not care* about your level of experience. We *do* care about you asking a clear, specific question ("please help me" [is not good enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)).

Comment: Please first try to solve the problem yourself (by *reading* and *understanding* the error message, by [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code, and by [doing research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/). If you are still stuck, ask the question clearly, by writing in complete sentences, and explaining the situation fully (including [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) error messages).

Comment: "(" Im a begginer so plz ignore my code mistakes and provide a solution)". No. We do not deal in "providing solutions" here; this is not a code-writing service, but a question- and-answer site. While your level of experience is not relevant to the question, being a beginner is exactly why you should *want* your code mistakes pointed out and corrected. That's how you stop being a beginner, by learning.

Comment: You shouldn't put the function definitions inside the `if` blocks. The functions need to be defined *before* you call them.

Comment: your code is quite literally written backwards, returns are not at the end, calls before definition, checking what to call after calling it

Comment: The code given here doesn't make any sense at all. It would be better if you re-read your tutorial material, starting from the beginning, and do each exercise as it comes up and *make sure you can make it work* before moving on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the input with strings, then call the corresponding function to get the appropriate discount.

Functions need to be defined before you can call them. Python doesn't allow forward-references to functions.

The functions get the amount as a parameter, they shouldn't prompt for it. Do that before calling the functions.

```
def student(x):
    return x - (x * (10 / 100))

def regular(y):
    return y - (y * (5 / 100))

purchaser = input("student or regular: ")
amount = float(input("Enter the price: "))

if purchaser == "student":
    print(student(amount))
elif purchase == "regular":
    print(regular(amount))
else:
    print("errroor")
```

You also need to use `elif` for the second condition. Otherwise, the final `else:` is only applied to the last `if`, so it will report an error for `student`.

Comment: "got it" @barmar